# iOS container view controller adds child's view in portrait orientaton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation, containment

I am developing an iPad app that should only support landscape orientation. I use these two methods to add a new child view controller to my container view controller:

```
- (void) assignFirstChildViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    self.currentChildViewController = controller;
    [self addChildViewController:self.currentChildViewController];
    [self.currentChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.currentChildViewController.view];

}
- (void)assignNewChildController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
{
    id currentChildViewController = self.currentChildViewController;

    if(!currentChildViewController){
        [self assignFirstChildViewController:childViewController];
    }else{

        [self.currentChildViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:childViewController];

        __weak __block PTSBaseContainerViewController *weakSelf=self;
        [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentChildViewController
                          toViewController:childViewController
                                  duration:1.0
                                   options:0
                                animations:^{
                                    [UIView transitionFromView:self.currentChildViewController.view toView:childViewController.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:NULL];
                                }
                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    [weakSelf.currentChildViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                    weakSelf.currentChildViewController = childViewController;
                                    [weakSelf.currentChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:weakSelf];
                                }];


    }
}
```

The problem is that the view of the child view controller is added in portrait orientation and it messes up the views as shown in the following image:

[image]

The green view is the view of the child view controller which as you can see is added in portrait mode. Instead of occupying the whole yellow view (which is the container view and it occupies the whole frame of the view controller beneath the grey top bar) it is being added in portrait mode and I cannot figure it why.

**PS:** I tried overriding `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` and `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` as written in the apple documentation but with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll see in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13), you need to manually set the frame for the child view controller.